# How to add more text to textarea

Tags: php, jquery, textarea

I want to create console.

I have textarea:

```
<textarea style="width: 100%; height: 300px; resize: none;" id="console_output" readonly></textarea>
```

And using this code to insert more text:

```
else echo "<script>$('#console_output').append('Some text.\n');</script>";
```

But nothing happened, textarea is empty.

Comment: Maybe the 'else' is not being hit.

Comment: Problem is javascript, because without javascript I can print text on screen.

Comment: I tried `echo "<script>$('#console_output').val($('#console_output').val()+'Neįvedėte jokios komandos!.\n');</script>";`, but its not work too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work as you can check [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qj13yt2t/)

```
$('#console_output').append('Some text.\n');
```

Will not work if

1. you are not into your else statement
2. textarea is not there yet if dynamically created
3. you have no jquery included

You can try with pure js:

```
echo '<script>document.getElementById("console_output").value += "Some text.\n";</script>';
```

Comment: But how I can use it with `echo`? I think my problem is wrong using in echo.

Comment: Text area created before php code, code reach else, jQuery included. Code works on blank script, its prints, but not with javascript. Pure not work too.

Comment: `echo "No text...";` - print successfuly

Comment: `<script>$('#console_output').append('Neįvedėte jokios komandos!.\n');</script>` works if I place it like html code, but in `echo` its not work.